# Determine a minimum ID is a known thecnic to optimize queries?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-tuning

I have a table with around 50 million of rows, and I need to do queries often. I realize that when I determine what is the minimum ID in `where` clause, the query is very faster.

For example:

```
select * from huge_table 
 where date <= '2016-03-01' 
 and date >= '2016-03-01 23:59:59';
```

However, if I know beforehand the lowest corresponding id, and use it as a where clause, thus here:

```
select * from huge_table 
 where id >= 
 (select id from huge_table where date >= '2016-03-01' limit 1) 
 and date <= '2016-03-01' 
 and date >= '2016-03-01 23:59:59';
```

the query is very faster.

Is it a known tuning approach? Has a name?

**update**:

There are indexes on `id` and `date` columns.

Here the EXPLAIN:
First query (without ID)

```
id   select_type table type     possible_keys            key        key_len ref   rows        Extra
'2', 'DERIVED',  't',  'ALL',   'PRIMARY,username,date', NULL,      NULL,   NULL, '21535250', 'Using where'
```

Second query (using ID):

```
id   select_type table type     possible_keys            key        key_len ref   rows        Extra
'2', 'DERIVED',  't',  'range', 'PRIMARY,username,date', 'PRIMARY', '8',    NULL, '5635840',  'Using where'
```

Comment: Do you have an index on the `id` column?

Comment: yes, and I updated the question

Comment: Are you sure there is indexes on the date column ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. There are indexes on both columns.

Comment: Can you print the result with "Explain select ..." ?

Comment: maybe interesting? [ANALYZE TABLE analyzes and stores the key distribution for a table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html)

Comment: ok, I updated the question

Comment: ok, I will prepare it. The table presented here is a example, the original structure table is more complex than this.